# Reading specific lines using read function

Tags: c

Assume I have a binary file `data.bin` of 1000 lines that was written using `fwrite`. For reading it, I just have to do something like this(where `data` is a double buffer of size 1000):

```
FILE *fp = fopen("data.bin", "rb");
fread(data, sizeof(double), (1000*sizeof(double),fp);
```

This will read the entire file but I am looking for reading only **the last** 500 lines!! This means I have to jump to the line 499 in `data.bin` and start reading from there until the end. How to do modify the previous `fread` function to read the last 500 lines?

Thank you.

Comment: what's a "*line*" in a binary file? Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the fseek() function. You need to set the pointer to begin at the last 500 lines then read until eof.

Look up fseek() and you will be able to solve this problem.

[Here is a link for further information on fseek()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm)

Comment: `fseek`!! Haven't read about it. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Will you? What offset would you use?

Comment: This *could* be formed into a correct answer as the OP doesn't seem to really *mean* "lines"...

Comment: It's clear that the user is using the sizeof a double to count the position in the file, so this answer is indeed relevant

Comment: @iiiiiii relevant and probably even in the right direction, but not an answer so far. It's better to wait for clarification before answering and it's really not a good idea to repeat misleading wording from the question. That said, The *duplicate* on the question is wrong as well, it should be reopened.